# [Operating system]Find the physical address given some logical address

Tags: paging

a logical-address space of 32 pages with page size 512 words,
mapped onto a physical memory of 128 frames

if page(11)in decimal is mapped onto frame (32)in decimal ,what is the physical address given that the logical address is (5800)?
I assumed that the page number and frame number start from 0.

I am confusing with this question.I know the bits for logical address is 2^14,physical address is 2^16.

But,i don't know to find a physical address.
Anyone help ?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

logical address 5800 is in page 11. Page 11 maps to frame 32. Then the physical address will be 512*32+(5800-11*512)=16552